# Python: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

Running into an issue with a project from [here](https://github.com/PiSugar/pisugar-server-py/)

Right off the bat when testing on Debian running python 3.7 it’s putting out errors, unfortunately I’m no coder and the devs don’t seem too responsive based on previous issues reported on their repos. I think it might be related to the float but what do I know.

`def connect_tcp(host="127.0.0.1", port=8423, timeout: float = None) -> tuple[socket.socket, socket.socket]: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Not tried much as not sure what do to.

Comment: I have a weak suspicion that you may not actually be using Python 3.5+. That error seems to be from the usage of the Python type hint for the return value `-> tuple[socket.socket, socket.socket]`. Which, these were only added to Python in 3.5. Try confirming that you're running Python 3.5+ with `python -- version`..?

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from `tuple[socket.socket, socket.socket]`.

This notation using `tuple` directly was implemented in python 3.9, for python up to 3.8 it was done through [`typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple).

You can add `from __future__ import annotation` (see [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html)) at the top of that file to turn on the postponed evaluation of annotations, which will allow you to run with any python from 3.7.

Comment: I think my celebration was a bit premature. It seems to work once and then if loaded a second time spits out the same error sadly.

Comment: What do you mean loaded a second time ? With postponed evaluation of annotations, you should not have any issue with type hints.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn’t worded correctly. What I meant is, once I have added from __future__ import annotation, I can then run some tests and it loads correctly. However if say I try and load the script again later in the day I end up with the original error again despite the script remaining the same.

Comment: @Insanelysick I cannot reproduce, if I put `from __future__ import annotations` on top of a file with `tuple[int, int, int]` I can run it several times with python 3.7 without issue.